# How to get distinct values of several fields in a single query in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

guys. If i have such mongo collection:

```
{ "author" : "author1", "title" : "title1", "edition" : "2010" }
{ "author" : "author2", "title" : "title1", "edition" : "2011" }
{ "author" : "author1", "title" : "title3", "edition" : "2010" }
```

how could i get something like this:

```
{"author":["author1", "author2"], "title":["title1", "title3"], "edition":["2010", "2011"]}
```

in a single query using distinct()?

I don't need any combinations of these items, i need arrays of unique values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/index.html) in `$group` aggregation

```
 db.col.aggregate([
    { 
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            author: { $addToSet: "$author" },
            title: { $addToSet: "$title" },
            edition: { $addToSet: "$edition" }
        }
    }
])
```